# How MoreLikeThis Works in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic

Lucene has a "more like this" feature, to find similar documents. How would I do this with MarkLogic?

Answer (score 5):

Try `cts:similar-query`: http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/apidoc/SearchBuiltins.xml&category=SearchBuiltins&function=cts:similar-query

Also take a look at http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0doc/docapp.xqy#display.xqy?fname=http://pubs/5.0doc/xml/search-dev-guide/similar.xml